# How to trim unspecific characters until one specific character?

Tags: python

In my case I have one sequence of characters that I need to trim from both sides.
The flanking region must reach the "=" and they are presented as:

Current:
"GGGGJTJTJTJS=======T=================================A=====GJTSGJGJGJT"

As a resulting sequence, I just want the "="-content fragment with the variants inside.

Expected:
"=======T=================================A====="

I tried this (but it doesn't work):

```
str = "GGGGJTJTJTJS=======T=================================A=====GJTSGJGJGJT"
for i in str:
 while str.startswith([x for x in [T,A]]):
  str = str.replace(x, "")
        
 while str.endswith([x for x in [T,A]):
  str = str.replace(x, "")
        
 print(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find()` and `rfind()` of string and slice the string between the returned indexes for them.

```
print(str[str.find("=")+1: str.rfind("=")])
```

Or by regex

```
import re

str = "GGGGJTJTJTJS=======T=================================A=====GJTSGJGJGJT"
print(re.search(r"(?=\=).*(?<=\=)", str).group())
```

Output

```
======T=================================A====
```

Comment: Preferable is string splicing, its 10x faster than regex.

Comment: That's correct just added another option of doing the task. Tnx for that

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

```
s=str.split('=',1)[1].rpartition('=')[0]
```

**What's this doing?**

- First Split On First Occurence Of = And Get The Poststring!
- Second Split From Last Occurence Of = And Get Back Your String!

*NOTE: I think the two delimeter characters *=* is also removed from start and end of string, so better append them manually if required, not a best way but probably better than what you were trying*